No Simulator runtime version from iPhoneSimulator
When i try to run my app through XCode iPhone simulator i get an error
"No simulator runtime version from [<DVTBuildVersion 21C62>, <DVTBuildVersion 21E213>, <DVTBuildVersion 21F79>] available to use with iphonesimulator SDK version <DVTBuildVersion 22A3362>"
I tried to update visual studio, xCode, restarting both machines, the error still remains.
I am on visual studio 2022, my project is using .net 8, and I am using XCode 16 for the simulator.

This is because the necessary iOS platform support isn't installed on the macOS machine.
You can fix it by:

Open Xcode
Open Xcode settings => Components
Make sure the platform component for the latest iOS version is installed (iOS 18.1 in this case, in Xcode 16.1):


For more information, you can check this github wiki: The build fails with "No simulator runtime version from ...".

Easy option is to launch Xcode and download the new simulator.
For other options see:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/installing-additional-simulator-runtimes

This happens with me yesterday, found that Xcode got update in background. Due to which new SDK wasn't installed (iOS 18.1).
Before installing new SDK, I've removed 18.0 SDK & associated simulators with it. After this "No simulator runtime version from [<DVTBuildVersion 21C62>, <DVTBuildVersion 21E213>, <DVTBuildVersion 21F79>] available to use with iphonesimulator SDK version <DVTBuildVersion 22A3362>" was gone.
